# User-access controlled photosharing web CMS

Tags: gratis, open-source, photography, cms, user-management

I am looking for a free and open source CMS/image management software that will let me:

- Divide users into groups and set photo viewing permission based on the groups
- Easily manage user data (ideally third party, e.g. like the list on Stack Exchange)

It should not require a database (but that is not essential).

So far [Piwigo](http://www.piwigo.org/) seems like the frontrunner. I’m keen to find other options though.

Comment: You haven't said what kind of server you will run it on. What constraints do you have? Do you have access to a MySQL database? Too many options. Node.JS? Wordpress? Both could be used I think and both would be able to handle external authentication such as OpenID or SAML.

Comment: @Julian I do not presently have access to a MySQL database but could get it if it's really required (more expensive hosting account). Re OS Linux preferred but, again, I could be persuaded.

Comment: Hmm, well piwigo requires MySQL or equivalent along with PHP. There are a LOT of possibilities but many of them will require some coding - for example to pull together both the gallery and the user management (from separate modules). I would normally reach for Wordpress with a plugin or two in these situations.

Comment: Thanks yes, I agree there seems to be a lot - that's why I asked really, to see which get recommended! Perhaps wordpress is a good choice.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "third party" user management?

Comment: @unor This means that I don't want to have to implement my own user access system* - third party might include mozilla persona, OpenID, wordpress, fbook, google etc (click on 'more options' on the stackexchange log in page to see others)

Comment: * unless there is some really easy method that I don't know about!

Answer (score 1):

Having got some more info from you, I'll stick my neck out and recommend WordPress.

There is a tag for [Photo Galleries](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/photo-gallery) in the Plugins list though I warn you many of them will be either rubbish or out of date - often both! Choose one that is rapidly updated, 4* or more and doesn't have too many negatives in the comments and you should find some great stuff in there.

This will give you not just the gallery but all of the supporting infrastructure such as user management, page management and tons more. If you don't want the hassle of managing your own users, pick one of the external [authentication](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=authentication) plugins.

Note, however, that you do need MySQL as well as PHP to run WordPress.