# Software for a private blog with access control

Tags: linux, open-source, web-apps

I've resorted to writing some web code to get the functionality I want, but it's taking a long time and meanwhile it would be nice to start blogging.

I looked for similar posts here on softwarerecs.stackexchange.com, and read these similar ones, but my requirements are a little different:

[CMS / blog software for articles and videos](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/21075/cms-blog-software-for-articles-and-videos)

[Private Web app for a couple, similar to social networks and team communication tools (self-hosted & free/libre)](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/27706/private-web-app-for-a-couple-similar-to-social-networks-and-team-communication)

[User-access controlled photosharing web CMS](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/5694/user-access-controlled-photosharing-web-cms)

Here are my requirements:

- Open source
- Installable on a Linux host
- Basically "install, configure and start publishing" - a little coding is OK, but it should not take too much time away from my main project
- Authentication - not required to see the site, only to access non-public articles. Single-factor is OK if necessary to avoid exernal dependencies.
- Ability to control which items each user or group of users can access
- No external dependencies (i.e., no requests other domains at runtime)
- Authoring page so (authenticated) non-technical people can contribute  articles
- Ability to put images in articles, with captions
- There must *not* be a registration form for anyone in the world to register an account (unless accounts require manual approval, so I can ignore uninvited would-be users)

I could simply put Wordpress on a domain, however according to what I've read it has only rudimentary access control and defaults to "open to the world", while a lot of my intended content will be only for specific groups of users.

Supposedly there are suitable plugins, however looking at the selection ( https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=authentication ) it seems that many of them are commercial-ware or depend on a vendor's servers. In addition, news reports about exploits suggest that Wordpress plugins are notoriously buggy. And apparently there are at least 28 pages of authentication plugins to choose from, each one needing to be looked at individually. So if you recommened Wordpress, could you please be specific about exactly which plugins would complete the requirements?