# Hosting simple html with authentication-only access

Tags: linux, security, self-hosted, privacy, authentication

I have this weird idea in my mind - like is it possible to host simple html page on my desktop the access to which is only accepted via an authentication key? I have a static IP and nowadays domain names are cheap. The desktop is running CentOS with the latest mainline kernel. My intention is to have a simple page where I can see plots from a weather station generated by a script executed as a chron job. The purpose of authentication is first and foremost security - since I keep my personal files on the computer and an attack would be devastating. Also that would ensure privacy.

A similar question has already been posted but there are no answers.

[Software for a private blog with access control](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/30024/software-for-a-private-blog-with-access-control)

Comment: Authentication will not affect the security of your personal files. If a web server has security issues, authentication doesn't help and if it has **no** security issues, the users should not be able to break out the directory you're serving anyways.

Comment: I guess my question should actually be - how to allow access to a port from outside similarly to how I have set a different ssh port and disabled password login? Does it make more sense?

Comment: Yes, but I don't see any relation to software rec.

Comment: I am sorry, I had initially misunderstood that security can be ensured by some alternative to Apache for example. My mistake. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: You could use a rootless container or a KVM virtual machine in a bridged setup and configure your router to let inbound (and established outbound) traffic pass. Then "simply" set up your webserver (e.g. nginx) to do authentication via client certificate and you should have a reasonably secure setup. Alternatively you could use any 2FA solution. Or you establish an adhoc SOCKS proxy via SSH and make sure that your plotted data is also served on - say - `http://localhost` (port 80). This way it's secured by SSH, which has a much better security track record than webservers.